# Probability - Color of Ball Which Selected

Tags: probability

**There are three boxes with the following contents :**

[image]

What is the probability that a ball which we choose is red?

Comment: How do we select? How many picks, from which boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have to choose one ball with each box being equally probable,

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P & = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{10} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{6}{10}+ \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{10} \\[0.2cm]
& = \frac{7}{15}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: from this formula?
[Pr(A)](http://p5x.co/26674)

Comment: Exactly. Bn is the event "choosing nth box" and A is the event "choosing red ball"